# Windows 7 x64 ram 3,90gb usable of 8gb after system reinstall

Tags: windows-7, memory

So just a while ago I had to reinstall my whole computer, for some reason after reinstall I have now 3,90gb usable ram out of possible 8gb. Cpu-z, bios, etc recognize that 8gb is installed but only 3,90gb is usable. Called customer service from where I bought these 2x 4gb's of ram, they say it's just badly installed and I should remove them from their slots and put them back in, but this didn't help either. Need help with this asap. Sorry for bad english

Comment: Either you installed the 32-bit version of Windows or you have memory remapping disabled in your BIOS.

Comment: Right-click on **Start > System** and check if it is x64 or x86 installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the way the memory is seated, and the customer services people advising you that are idiots.

Almost certainly you are running Windows 7 32 bit - which is limited to 4 gigs of RAM less a bit for the graphics controller.  You would need to install the 64 bit version to see more then 4 gigs of ram.  See [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/33345-63-extend-limit-win7-32bit) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7).   (Note X86 = 32 bit.)

Comment: They are idiots, yes. But it's x64 and I'm pretty sure of that. One of my friends says it could be because my version of windows is "fake". could it be true?

Comment: I'd imagine so.   Why not download a Linux distro, boot it off a USB drive and see what it shows.  As a bonus, many Linux distros have a tool to do memory testing so you can see what that does as well.

Comment: I assumed that a part of it is reserved by the intergrated graphics. and maybe some other hardware components too.

Comment: @ProtoAES256 some RAM would be reserved but 4GB would be unreasonable.

Comment: @RsyaStudios hmm